# Excluir item do recyclerView a partir do Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Estou tentando aplicar uma funcionalidade, clicando em um ícone dentro de uma lista de um RecyclerView.
Ao clicar no ícone, eu registro a aceitação da condição, caso não aceite, o "item todo" deve ser excluído da lista. Estou tentando fazer isto de dentro do Adapter, acredito que seja no `onBindViewHolder`, porque eu quero o clique apenas no ícone do item, e não no item todo, até porque terei outros ícones com outras funções.
Não estou conseguindo excluir o item da lista:

Adapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dim_mid"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dim_mid"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dim_normal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_normal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/civUsuario"
            style="@style/ImgPerfil"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nome"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStatus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icone03"
            style="@style/IconesStatus" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icone02"
            style="@style/IconesStatus" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icone01"
            style="@style/IconesStatus" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter Java:

`List<Usuario> usuarios;`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.icone01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Executo a verificação
            if (false) {
                // Condição aceita
            } else {
                usuarios.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Este código não funciona... o item não é excluído...
Alguém sabe me informar qual seria a forma correta de se fazer isto? Preciso executar de dentro do Adapter para atribuir o onClick apenas ao ícone específico, ou acessar o ícone, atribuindo um onClick a ele de fora do Adapter, pelo recyclerView talvez... Não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Seu ImageView com id "icone01" precisa da propriedade `android:clickable="true"`.

Answer (score -2):

Inclua mais essa função

```
             if (false) {
            // Condição aceita
        } else {
            usuarios.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, usuarios.size()); 
                  

        }
```